# Defining the format of the mighty Stack Exchange engine

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Stack Exchange is such a great and awesome dear leader. Its format has been the fruity inspiration to many other sites and wannabes.

Has the format of the Stack Exchange engine (from an editorial point of view) been defined in a word of some concrete fashion?

We all know what a wiki, a blog or a forum is.

How would you define the Frankenstein's monster of this format meshing of a given site of Q&A in the Stack Exchange Galactic Empire?

Answer (score 3):

The diagram from [the Stack Overflow about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) covers it.

[image]

In a few words, I guess I'd say **editable voting/reputation based Q&A system**.

I do hope that the Stack Exchange engine becomes the iPod of its category. In other words, when people think "handheld digital music player" the iPod is the clear leader and sets the best example of how to do it right.

Comment: So it should be e.v.r.b.Q.&.A.s.? :-) Ok, let's say there is NOT yet an editorial definition of this format. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, the iPod might indeed be the clear leader in terms of sales/user base in the handheld digital music player space, but an overpriced totally locked down device is not really what I would call a "best example of how to do it right".