# What is the Stack Exchange system called

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format definition of Stack Exchange engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/format-definition-of-stack-exchange-engine)

When trying to discuss Stack Exchange I find myself saying forum which is clearly wrong.  Is there a name for the type of system that we should be using?

I tried Community Driven Answer System (CDAS) but it just sounds stupid.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stackoverflow-a-forum http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54533/explaining-stack-exchange-to-non-programmers

Comment: Actually, I kinda like "Community-Driven Answer System."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Q&A site" or just "Stack Exchange" has worked well for me.